How can I create a table using SQL Alchemy if that table exists inside a schema?
I created a short Python script to create a single table.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase

class MyBase(DeclarativeBase):
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'my_schema'}
    
class MyTable(MyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

url = 'postgresql://user:pass@host/database'
engine = create_engine(url)

MyBase.metadata.tables['my_schema.my_table'].create(engine)

If I run this, I obtain the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidSchemaName) schema "my_schema" does not exist

What do I have to do to get SQLAlchemy to create the schema if it does not exist, and ignore it if it does exist? (I intend to write multiple "create table" scripts as I add new tables and my application grows.)

A possible solution which requires manually creating the schema. (Not ideal imo)
Add this first.
from sqlalchemy import create_engine text

engine = create_engine(...)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(text("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS my_schema"))
    conn.commit()

